# Composite layer by distance

Tags: qgis-3, nearest-neighbor, grouping

I've got a complicated problem right now. I have a layer with polygons and use the tool "Closest Neighbor" to find all Polygons that have a neighbor within 10 meters.
That works fine, but now I have to "group" them; So I would like to have differnt layers for each group.
The function does not give my polygons a new field with a group ID;

For example: 10 Polygons build a group couse they have at least one neighbor closer than 10 meters in the gropup;
there is another group of 4 Polygons close to the first group, but its closest distance is 12 metres to the first group.

Showing all groups in one layer works but it is complicated to see wich polygon belongs to wich group.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a buffer around your polygons and dissolve it. Now each group of dissolved buffers correspond to a group. You can make an overlay with your original polygons, e.g. to create a new attribute with a `group_id`.

For buffering, select `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Buffer`, select the polygon layer, set the distance (2 m in my case) and check the box near dissolve results (at the bottom).

*Screnshot: original polygons in orange, dissolved buffers in blue:*
[image]

For the overlay, select `Menu Vector / Geometry tools / Single part to multiparts` to have a separate feature for each buffer-polygon. Than use the field calculator to generate a new field `group` and use this expression (`overlay_within` is available since QGIS 3.16) :

```
array_first (
    overlay_within(
        'single parts', 
        $id
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: see how to create a new field. I used the field already created to label the original polygons:*
[image]