# How to identify "island" polygons?

Tags: postgis, polygon, vector

I am curious how can I find all polygons that are touching with each other but are completely separate from the rest of the polygons is the same dataset, using PostGIS.

For better understanding I uploaded a picture.

[image]

Comment: Are they MultiPolygon data type?

Comment: Yes, but usually they consists of one polygon. Every polygon you see on the picture is separate from others, but every one is defined as MultiPolygon  in a database.

Comment: I don't really understand even with the picture ... Is the question from your picture is : how to find an entire square ? If so, merge / dump and intersect with itself, if no intersections and contains more than 1 origin polygon, it is what you search.

Comment: PgRouting should work but it requires some pre-processing. Nodes that you cannot access from a start node belong to other islands.

Comment: I think you may be looking for clustering based on intersection? If so, try [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408716/93656).

Comment: See this solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/390276/88814 : buffer your polygons and dissolve the buffer to get groups of contiguous polygons. Use a very small buffer size or even a size of 0.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/343527/14766),  use `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` to assign an id to each touching group of polygons:

```
SELECT *,
       ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, 0, 1) OVER() AS clst_id
FROM   poly_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can merge touching polygons, see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49970447/2816941

This will produce a layer for these "islands".

Then you can simply join back onto the islands from the original data using `st_intersects(islands.geom, st_pointonsurface(original.geom))`